# Possible to start up Jenkins again via ..war file even though the machine where Jenkins is deployed restarts?

Tags: java, jenkins, deployment, virtual-machine

Is it possible to start up Jenkins again via .war even though the machine where Jenkins is deployed restarts?

I have jenkins deployed on a Virtual machine using a .war file with the following command: java -jar jenkins.war

If the machine gets restarted, the command prompt which is using the above command closes and therefore stops my instance of Jenkins from running.

Is there a way to automatically start up Jenkins again even if the machine gets restarted?

VM is using windows 2008 server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Msconfig in Run > startup programs > add your command.
It will be executed on start of OS.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a batch file and pasting in the following location has resolved the issue: C:\Users\zzzzzz\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup